# animation does not apply to a button with background

Tags: android, animation

I have a button defined in my layout file. When the button is clicked, I assign an animation to it as follow:

```
   Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f);
            animation.setRepeatCount(-1);
            animation.setDuration(2000);
mybutton.setAnimation(animation);
```

all things work fine to this point. But problem is raised when I set any background to my button specially `android:background="@null"` in button definition.

Any idea on how to fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: fix animation when button has background

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried this in my project and it works on a button with a background.

```
private ObjectAnimator rotationAnimator;
```

and the functions to control the animation

```
private void startAnimation(int animationDuration) {

    if (rotationAnimator == null || !rotationAnimator.isRunning()) {
        // You can tweak this to your needs
        Keyframe kf0 = Keyframe.ofFloat(0f, 0f);
        Keyframe kf2 = Keyframe.ofFloat(0.5f, 180f);
        Keyframe kf1 = Keyframe.ofFloat(1f, 360f);

        PropertyValuesHolder pvhRotation = PropertyValuesHolder.ofKeyframe("rotation", kf0, kf1, kf2);
        rotationAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(your_button_here, pvhRotation);
        rotationAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        rotationAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        rotationAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
        rotationAnimator.start();
    }
    else {
        Log.d("Animation", "I am already running!");
    }
}

private void stopAnimation() {
    if (rotationAnimator != null) {
        rotationAnimator.cancel();
        rotationAnimator = null;
    }
}

private boolean getAnimationRunning() {
    return rotationAnimator != null && rotationAnimator.isRunning();
}
```

Comment: As I said when I apply any background the animation does not play and no matter what is the background.

Comment: I have posted some code I just tried out and it seems to be working on my end using one plus with android 5.1.1